# Convert a list to a object c#

Tags: c#, list, object, deserialization

I have a common method which accepts any paramater as object

```
public static object Populate(object anyStuff)
{

}
```

I to send a List of a user defined class to this. and then de serialize it again in the method to loop through it. I am not sure how to accomplish.

Comment: You shouldn't pass in object because it is almost guarranteed to cause errors at some point, you say you pass in a list of your class so why not have a `List<T>` parameter? (or `ienumerable<t>` as above)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Where you can create the generic method that handles different type of list and operates on them:

```
public static T Populate<T>(List<T> list){
    //Do stuff
}
```

But if you are using talking about object (do note, not a good way you are trying to achieve):

```
public static object Populate(object anyStuff){
   //Explicit typecast
   List<string> value = anyStuff as List<string>();
}
```

If you want to know the usage of the first example with generic, here you can see the [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic-method)

Comment: No idea what the return type should be.. Question doesn't have enough info... I wouldn't be sure of the signature suggested with return of type `T`.

Comment: @VikasGupta quiet a bit made sense with the question when the user already has return of object, he would want some generic object back. But agreed the OP should provide more info, yet the first Generics link was to educated him

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would create multiple overloads of Populate.

If I read your question correctly, you'd like something like this:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Name", "Bart"},
    {"Date", new DateTime(2014,9,23)},
    {"Age", 300}
}
var item = HelperClass.Populate(properies)

Console.WriteLine(item.Name); // should print "bart"
```

If this is what you want, you should look into the dynamic ExpandoObject.
(see http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/06/converting-any-object-to-dynamic.html )

```
public static dynamic Populate(IDictionary<string, object> anystuff)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject()
    foreach(var key in anystuff)
    {
        expando[key] = anystuff[key];
    }
    return expando;
}
```